# Создание двусвязного списка с рядом функций

Tags: c++

Помогите написать программу на двусвязный список с функциями на:
-Вставку в начало
-вставку в конец
-вставку в определенную позицию по условию
-извлечение из конца
-извлечение из конца
-сортировку пузырьком
Основная моя беда в том, что нужно сделать файловый ввод и вывод.
Если не жалко времени

Answer (score 0):

Ну если *Основная беда* в файловом вводе/выводе, то вот кусочек с предположением, что ваша программа запускается из консоли в виде `your_awesome_program input_file.txt output_file.txt`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

bool readFile(char** argv, YourCustomList& list)
{
    std::string fileName = argv[1];
    std::fstream file;
    file.open(inputFileName);

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "file wasn't open" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.clear();
    ss.str("");

    int m; //указываем количество и типы переменных
    std::string input = "";

    // считываем построчно из предположения что одна
    // строка  - одно значение
    while (getline(file, input))
    {
        ss.str(input);
        if (!(ss >> m))
            break;
        // вставляем считанное значение в ваш list
        list.insert(m);
        ss.clear();
        ss.str("");
        input.clear();
    }
    return true; //Happy End!
}

void writeFile(YourCustomList const &list, char** argv)
{
    std::string outputFileName = argv[2];
    std::ofstream fout(outputFileName);

    // записываем построчно значения из вашего списка list
    for (auto& number : list) {
    fout << number  << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << std::flush;
    fout.close();
}
```

только int main() надо записать как: `int main (int argc, char** argv)` и будет вам счастье.

```
в main():
вначале создаете свой список;
потом запускаете readFile();
затем какие-то промежуточные операции;
в конце writeFile();
и return 0;
```

Comment: А как это в целом впихнуть в саму программу и нужно ли что то изменять в функциях, чтобы работало? И можно ли это всё закинуть в один контейнер?

Comment: если ваша программа вообще не подразумевает ручного ввода, то делаете программу для запуска из командной строки в виде my_list_program input_file.txt outout_file.txt.    и пишите int main(int argc, char** argv)....  разбирать argc и вы умеете? получается argv[1] будет ваш input_file.txt, argv[2] - ваш out_put file. тогда немного надо будет функции поменять. Вам это выложить или сами справитесь?

Comment: Выложите пожалуйста, если вам не трудно

Comment: выложил. Как написал в ответе, обязательно  создайте свой список до чтения файла. т.к. ваш созданный список функция readFile() принимает по ссылке.

Comment: Правда моя программа изначально отличается немного от того, как пишете вы. Я не совсем понимаю, как отправить вам свою программу, потому что с вставкой функций ввода и вывода возникли небольшие траблы.

Comment: я тоже не совсем представляю, но в целом, согласно традициям, если вы пишите все в одном файле, то до main() описываете свой класс списка, эти две функции и потом `int main (int argc, char** argv) {`  `YourCustomList list;` `bool success = readFile(argv, list)` и далее как указано в конце моего ответа

Comment: Если не много, то скиньте ссылку с любого code share ресурса

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста http://collabedit.com/uqkg9

Comment: А в самом Визуал Студио почему то не хочет принимать stringstream ss;

Comment: Я немного дописал и подправил функцию, но есть пару нареканий. У вас отдельно реализована функция добавления первого элемента списка. и отдельно все остальные. Предлагаю вам включить функцию добавления первого элемента непосредственно внутрь функции добавления элементов, пуем проверки `если список не пуст, то просто добавляете, иначе используете функцию добавления элемента`. таким образом у людей, использующих ваш класс,  не будет голова болеть, когда какое добавление использовать. Так же необходимо использовать функцию `void List::Show()`  с аргументом.

Comment: Где аргумент это будет тип вывода , чтобы можно было выводить как на экран так и в файл. Так вот поверхностно осмотрев в 3 ночи, вроде бы все.

Comment: Я вроде бы понял, огромное спасибо за помощь

Comment: `#include <sstream>` для std::stringstream